# Xamarin Android AWS Error getting response stream (ReadDoneAsync2): ReceiveFailure

Tags: xamarin.android, aws-sdk

Updated visual studio to 15.8.5 and AWS library AWSSDK.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication stopped working with error above

```
Amazon.AWSConfigs.AWSRegion = AWSConfigConstants.Region;
var provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(),                                                       FallbackRegionFactory.GetRegionEndpoint());
var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(AWSConfigConstants.PoolId, AWSConfigConstants.ClientId, provider);
var user = new CognitoUser(model.UserName, AWSConfigConstants.ClientId, userPool, provider);

authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
                        {
                            Password = model.Password
                        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug related to mono update: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1068